# Android Tv - Now playing card icon

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I am currently working on a android tv app but cant figure out how to change the icon for the now playing card that appears when i navigate away from the app whilst playing a video.

This [link](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/now-playing.html) show that i need to set MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI with a uri formatted string but i either cant get the string formatted correctly or it does not work for some other reason.

currently i have this string -

```
"android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/drawable/app_icon_new"
```

full extract

```
 final MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();

    String title = video.getArtist().replace("_", " -");

    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, title);
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE,
            video.getTrack());
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, title);
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, video.getArtist());

    String uri = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/drawable/app_icon_new";
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI, uri);



    Glide.with(this)
        .load(Uri.parse(video.getThumbnailUrl()))
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(500, 500) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ART, bitmap);
                mSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
            }
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: spacemonkey391, I'm having problems with starting a custom activity when the user presses on the Now Playing card. Can you please share the relevant code?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053596/now-playing-card-does-not-start-the-desired-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no way to change the Now Playing Icon as you can change it in the Recommendation Card.
I hope that they'll fix this in a further update.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the icon used in Now Playing Card is the one specified in your Manifest, in android:icon attribut of the application node.

Answer (score 0):

This currently works:

```
metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI, String.valueOf(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable)));
```