# Now Playing Card Does Not Start the Desired Activity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-tv

I could not manage to start an activity from the Now Playing card. I am using the following code, but the NowPlayingActivity never gets called.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NowPlayingCardActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 99, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mSession.setSessionActivity(pi);
```

and in the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".NowPlayingCardActivity" />
```

I am taken to the main activity when I click on the Now Playing card, and the NowPlayingCardActivity is not called.

NowPlayingActivity:

```
public class NowPlayingCardActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = "NowPlayingCardActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        Intent newIntent;

        newIntent = new Intent(this, ChannelDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(newIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Edit:
I added the following code to NowPlayingCardActivity, but to no avail...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}
```

Comment: Is it correct that the NowPlayingCardActivity should never be shown? Since you are calling the finish() method in onCreate, that means it'll close itself while it is starting.

Comment: Yes, it is just a proxy activity for testing. I don't see the log entry in logcat and the debugger does not stop, so I assume that the activity is never called.

Comment: FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT - _Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent._ So maybe onCreate() is not called, but only onResume() or onStart().

Comment: @McGee, I added the onResume and onStart methods (Edit 1), but to no avail... The main activity is being called instead of NowPlayingCardActivity

Comment: What is in this method? `mSession.setSessionActivity(pi);`

Comment: @McGee, it is from the Respond to Action section in https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/now-playing.html

Comment: This git repo looks to have what you want. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/MusicService.java

Comment: Thanks, but I already had looked at it, and could not see what I was doing different and wrong...

Comment: Try to put a break point on your intent NowPlayingCardActivity line & check in debug if it's calling that line, and also try changing request code from 99 to something above 1000 as PendingIntent has issues with some devices running on or above android 4.3 (change only if you are testing your app with any of these android versions)

Comment: @amrit, I tried both of your suggestions, but to no avail... I guess there's something wrong or missing with mSession.setSessionActivity(pi);